# Validate SSN in a HL7 medssage for duplicate SSN

Tags: integration, hl7

I need to Validate SSN in such a way that redundant entry should not appear. for example if a message arrives for Patient A with ssn 123-45-6789 and next time if any message comes for Patient B with same ssn, integration engine should catch this. I am using cloverleaf as a integration engine and need to validate this. 
please let me know if any logic can be suggested.

Thanks,
Anupam..

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't be a valid use case for an integration engine. You should look into acquiring a master patient index application and integrate it into your message flow.

Even then, with HL7 messaging there is generally no 100% reliable source of truth to tell you who is Patient A and who is Patient B. For example, if you get a second message for SSN 123-45-6789 and the name doesn't match the first patient is that because it's really a different person or did the patient perhaps legally change her name?

Finally relying on SSNs in health care systems is generally considered a **bad idea** due to the security and privacy concerns. Most modern systems actually filter out SSNs and rely on other fields to identify the patient.